# Object manipulation using functions

Tags: c++, class, oop

I am currently working on a Fraction class for school.  Our textbook wants our functions to manipulate the values as shown in the main code.  Why are the values for m_numer and m_denom not being updated?

```
class Fraction
{
public:
    Fraction();
    Fraction(int numer, int demon);
    void Add(Fraction left_frac, Fraction right_frac)const;
    void Subtraction(Fraction let_frac, Fraction right_frac)const;
    Fraction & Multiply(Fraction let_frac, Fraction right_frac)const;
    void Divide(Fraction let_frac, Fraction right_frac)const;
    void Display() const;
    int GetNumer() const;
    void SetNumer(int numer);
    int GetDenom() const;
    void SetDenom(int denom);
    ~Fraction();

private:
    int m_numer;
    int m_denom;
    void reduce();
};

Fraction & Fraction::Multiply(Fraction left_frac, Fraction right_frac) const
{
    Fraction result;

    result.m_numer = left_frac.GetNumer() * right_frac.GetNumer();
    result.m_denom = left_frac.GetDenom() * right_frac.GetDenom();

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    Fraction f1 (1, 2),
             f2 (3, 4), 
             f3;

    f3.Multiply(f1, f2);

    f1.Display();
    cout << " * ";
    f2.Display();
    cout << " = ";
    f3.Display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand your question

Comment: when calling f3.Multiply(f1, f2), the values for m_numer and m_denom should be saved into f3.  However, with my current code, this is not happening.

Comment: I think Add etc should be friends and not members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is creating a new Fraction and returning it.

```
Fraction & Fraction::Multiply(Fraction left_frac, Fraction right_frac) const
{
    Fraction result;

    result.m_numer = left_frac.GetNumer() * right_frac.GetNumer();
    result.m_denom = left_frac.GetDenom() * right_frac.GetDenom();

    return result;
}
```

If you instead want it to modify the value of the fraction you can change it so it looks like this.

```
void Fraction::Multiply(Fraction left_frac, Fraction right_frac)
{
    m_numer = left_frac.GetNumer() * right_frac.GetNumer();
    m_denom = left_frac.GetDenom() * right_frac.GetDenom();
}
```

In your example, this would make `f3 = f1 * f2`.

Comment: `return result;` is invalid; it's returning a reference to a dead variable.

Comment: @melpomene You're right. Removed `const`. The `return result` is just copied from the question for clarity. I'm aware it's not correct.